# Publishing from sbt to a local maven repo

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

I added the following to the `build.sbt`

```
publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file",  new File(Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository")))

publishMavenStyle := true
```

Publishing does not seem to have been affected: the following

```
 sbt publishLocal
```

The result is apparently still going to the `ivy` instead of `.m2` repo:

```
Packaging /git/msSCSCTEL/streaming-reconciler/target/scala-2.10/streaming-reconciler_2.10-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar ...
Done packaging.
    published streaming-reconciler_2.10 to /Users/myuser/.ivy2/local/com.mycomp/streaming-reconciler_2.10/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/poms/streaming-reconciler_2.10.pom
    published streaming-reconciler_2.10 to /Users/myuser/.ivy2/local/com.mycomp/streaming-reconciler_2.10/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/jars/streaming-reconciler_2.10.jar
    published streaming-reconciler_2.10 to /Users/myuser/.ivy2/local/com.mycomp/streaming-reconciler_2.10/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/srcs/streaming-reconciler_2.10-sources.jar
    published streaming-reconciler_2.10 to /Users/myuser/.ivy2/local/com.mycomp/streaming-reconciler_2.10/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/docs/streaming-reconciler_2.10-javadoc.jar
    published ivy to /Users/myuser/.ivy2/local/com.mycomp/streaming-reconciler_2.10/0.1.0-SNAPSHOT/ivys/ivy.xml
```

What is missing/incorrect to publish to maven instead?

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan  Please make that an answer. If you would not mind also add how/where you found that tidbit

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `publishM2`. I've looked through the docs, but I can't find any reference to this command. I've discovered it simply by writing `publish` in the sbt console and then hitting the tab key a couple of times.

Comment: Wow. We need person with magic fingers like that on our project.

Comment: I still can't find a reference in the docs but it still works in sbt 1.0.1